# Django render on the same template

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views, python-3.6

I try to create a pagination, so i use a some lines of JS to send data, i catch it correctly (and can print it in the console) and i see they are different but my render never change.

*Console.log:*

```
[15/Mar/2017 14:30:09] "POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15320
[POST] 2
[15/Mar/2017 14:30:10] "POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9003
[POST] 3
[15/Mar/2017 14:30:10] "POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9003
[POST] 4
[15/Mar/2017 14:30:16] "POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9003
[POST] 1
```

*Template.html:*

```
<p> THIS IS THE PAGE {{ page }} </p>

<div class="col-xs-12 center">
  <ul class="pagination" >
    <li><a href="#" value={{ page|add:"-1" }}>&laquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value=0>1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value=1>2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value=2>3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value=3>4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value=4>5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value={{ page|add:"1" }}>&raquo;</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
    $('ul.pagination li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/index/',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            data: {'page': $(this).attr('value')},
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            processData: true,       
        });
    })
</script>
```

*Views.py:*

```
def index(request):
    print("[POST]",request.POST.get('page'))
    page = int(request.POST.get('page', 0)) 
    return render(request, "site/index.html",
                         {'page': page})
```

So I think if i'm on `/index/` i can't do a new render of index with new variable (and new render with this variable as well) ?

Do you have an idea when i can do that ?

EDIT: i add console log prove i catch the value of `page` with JS.

Comment: Could you try Django's built-in `Paginator` class? You wouldn't need the javascript code, but it would refresh the page every time you changed a page. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/

Comment: That a good way, but i really trying to rewrite or overwrite the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the page already format in HTML by the Django rendering engine, use the function in ajax to to overwrite a the current page : `$("html").html(response);` so just adjust the javascript part.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('ul.pagination li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/index/',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            data: {'page': $(this).attr('value')},
            'success': function(response)
            {
                $("body").html(response);
            }      
        });
   })
</script>
```